# Как настроить горячую клавишу для открытия "Мои сообщения" Вконтакте (Windows)

Tags: windows

Как настроить горячую клавишу (например "(" ), чтобы открывать сообщения Вконтакте?

Comment: поясните, что вы имеете в виду. какую кнопку? где?

Comment: создать горячую клавишу для перехода в (Мои сообщения)

Comment: на каком устройстве?

Comment: ПК ( на платформе Windows 7)

Comment: можно ли так сделать? или смысла нету задавать такой вопрос?

Comment: в браузере точно можно сделать закладку. но я вам рекомендую добавить эту информацию в вопрос - так вы скорее получите ответ.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не относится к программированию.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы создадите на рабочем столе ярлык на нужную страницу, то можно будет зайти в его свойства и задать сочетание клавиш для быстрого вызова.

Одну кнопку для этого использовать нельзя, можно только сочетание из Ctrl+Alt+Ещё_одна_клавиша.

Подробнее вы можете нагуглить по запросу "windows пользовательские горячие клавиши".

Например, здесь есть подробная инструкция с картинкой:

http://setupcomp.ru/index_page1.html
(Пролистайте эту страницу чуть ниже, до заголовка "Как назначить горячие клавиши")